# How to make .txt files visible to Visual C

Tags: c, visual-studio-2013, scanf, assertion

I'm writing a program to that needs to read 32-bit binary numbers in as strings from a text file (notepad). The file contents look like this:

```
11111111111111110111100011111110
11111111111111111111111111110101     
00000000100001011010101011110101         
00000000000000000000000010010001
```

Every time I try to run the code I get the error message saying that the debug assertion failed because the (stream != NULL) condition was not satisfied. I assume that this comes from an error with the fscanf part of the code. I have looked at similar questions with the solution usually being to move the text file to the current working directory, but I am not sure what this means. I am using visual studio Express 2013, and have the text file saved under resource files in my console application. I also have the console application and the text file saved in a single folder on my desktop. Neither of these seem to have had any effect in resolving the error. Here is my source code if it helps at all:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>

void main()
{
    char str[34];
    FILE *binnz;
    binnz = fopen("binns.txt", "r");
    while (fscanf(binnz,"%s",str) != EOF)
    {
        printf("%s\n", str);
    }
    fclose(binnz); 
}
```

If the problem is where the text file is stored, where -exactly- do I put it?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

> I have looked at similar questions with the solution usually being to move the text file to the current working directory, but I am not sure what this means.

The working directory of a program basically allows it to open files by a relative path. Typically, the working directory of a program will be wherever the executable file resides (so it can easily reference files in the same directory); however, when debugging in Visual Studio, it'll use the project directory as the working directory by default. You can change this under the "Debugging" page of your project settings, or you can just put `binns.txt` in your project directory.

Answer (score 0):

The resource directory is the wrong place.   Add a **system("dir")** to your program, and it will show you where your program is running.   Put your file in there, and you should be good to go.